# Crow's Foot Database Notation Visio 2013

Tags: visio

This may seem a dumb question but I am struggling with **Visio 2013** and the "Crow's Foot Database Notation" template in one very simple area:  I have a table object on the diagram.  It defaults to a PK plus two columns.How does one add columns? I have looked around (MS help is useless, as usual) and cannot find out how to do this simple act.

Answer (score 6):

You can drag the "Attribute" shape from the stencil and drop it into "Entity" shape (the "Entity" shape is now a container shape, so it will auto-size)

The background addon which you had in all previous versions of Visio was discontinued in 2013, so you have now are just shapes.